# Python - deleting a DM in Discord with on_raw_reaction_add

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have my Discord bot delete messages when reacting with an emoji. I have some code for it, which works in a Discord server, but it does not work in DMs

This is my code

```
self = discord.Bot()
@self.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(ctx):
    if ctx.emoji.name == '❌':
        message = await self.get_channel(ctx.channel_id).fetch_message(ctx.message_id)
        await message.delete()
```

This is the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'
```

Since I figure DMs apparently don't have "channels", I've tried getting just the specific message ID with

```
message = ctx.message_id
```

but I can't find any way to delete messages by ID that works with on_raw_reaction_add

All the similar questions I've found here about deleting bot DMs aren't working with on_raw_reaction_add. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `user.fetch_message` to fetch a message in a `DMChannel`. So you could check if the channel exists, and if it does not, you can get the user instead.

Example:

```py
@self.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(ctx):
    if ctx.emoji.name == "❌":
        channel = self.get_channel(ctx.channel_id)
        if not channel:
            channel = await self.fetch_user(ctx.user_id)

        message = await channel.fetch_message(ctx.message_id)

        await message.delete()
```

Please keep in mind that you will **not** be able to delete the messages of the other person, only your own bot's messages. This is a discord limitation.

Comment: I defined my bot as `self`. Sorry, I updated my post with that info. This example gives me `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'bot'`.

If I redo the example, I'm still getting a NoneType with `channel = self.get_user(ctx.user_id)`, then I get the same error in my question when I'm trying to define `message`.

Comment: @Kilvoctu If you get None with the user_id, you could try fetching the user instead of looking the user up in cache. I have updated my answer, it works on my end, I hope it works for you too.